# How to learn the Bluetooth technology from zero

Tags: bluetooth, profile, android-bluetooth

I have been learn about some knowledge of Android system,  and I want to learn the Bluetooth technology systematically. How can i do start to learn it. Could you provider some books for me or a good route map to learn it.
Any suggestions will be appreciate. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also New to Bluetooth, 
I have started reading from the Book called " Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy " ( https://g.co/kgs/6db4nf ).. This might be very useful to know about the following important things to get started and connect with BLE devices,

1. What is Bluetooth Low Energy
2. How to get the Services from the BLE device
3. How to get the Characteristics
4. What are the Descriptors
5. How to Read the Indications from the BLE device.

Thanks